# Cannot add nuget packages

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Downloaded Visual Studio 14 CTP and I cannot add nuget references.  What's more thenuget references that should automatically come down when you create a web project aren't there either which means I cannot run the application.

I am running Windows 7 on a VM in Parallels on my Mac (not sure if that's the cause of the issue).

I know that the way that nuget packages are downloaded has changed and they are now in a global folder in your user profile? instead of in a packages folder of the project.  From a bit of research online the packages should be found at: %userprofile%.kpm but there is no .kpm folder inside my user profile folder.

Here is a screenshot of what the references node looks like inside solution explorer (as you can see the references doesnt have the little arrow showing it can be expanded):

[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open the output window, set it to show output from "Package Manager Log", then open the project.json and save it (this triggers a package restore), are there now any errors in your output window?

Comment: You might need to "Repair" Visual Studio. Also, check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages` to see if the packages are there. I think the packages in `...\.kpm` are only packages that have been restored - they are not the "source of truth" for sources.

Comment: What version of VS is this?  There is no Visual Studio 2014

Comment: This was the first released name of Visual Studio 2015 @NathanOliver. It's been appropriately retagged.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Are you not changing the "Visual Studio 2014" in the title and question?

Answer (score 0):

Either repair VS and create a new project as mentioned in another answer above, or if that does not work try using the current VS replacing the 2014 CTP, which is Ultimate 2015 preview.